# How to get value of td by id in c# regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I have following html, there more td's but have put only few of below. I want to get value of value of TD which has id "hdNumber" through c# code.I want to use regular expression. sometime when come generate html from window live for (email) it may be possible that it render html like "8332 without quotation marks before and after id. I want to get number 8332 only.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <TD style="COLOR: #666" vAlign=top>
         Good<TD>
       <TD id="hdNumber"
       style="BACKGROUND: white; COLOR: white; DISPLAY: none">8332
    </TD> 
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: obligatory [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 2):

[Don't use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/284240). You can use [`HtmlAgilityPack`](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlString);
var hdNumber = doc.GetElementbyId("hdNumber");
if(hdNumber != null)
{
    string number = hdNumber.InnerText.Trim('\r', '\n', ' ', '"');  // 8332
}
```

I have used `Trim('\r', '\n', ' ', '"')` to remove possible leading and trailing spaces, newline characters and quotes as desired.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use regular expression.

You can use the following with `s` modifier or `DOTALL` if you don't want to use DOM Parser (recommended) :

```
<TD\s*id\s*=\s*"?hdNumber"?.*?>(.*?)</TD>
```

And extract number with `$1`

See [DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3CTD%5Cs*id%5Cs*%3D%5Cs*%22%3FhdNumber%22%3F.*%3F%3E(.*%3F)%3C%2FTD%3E&i=%3Ctable%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTD%20style%3D%22COLOR%3A%20%23666%22%20vAlign%3Dtop%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Good%3CTD%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CTD%20id%3D%22hdNumber%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3D%22BACKGROUND%3A%20white%3B%20COLOR%3A%20white%3B%20DISPLAY%3A%20none%22%3E8332%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FTD%3E%20%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftable%3E&r=%241&o=s)

Comment: thanks karthik,but when I used that in my below c# code it is not working.` const string pattern = @"<TD\s*id\s*=\s*""?hdNumber""?.*?>(.*?)</TD>"; Match match in Regex.Matches(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`

Comment: @Sandip ..yeah thats because you assumed there will be a space after `id=\s` .. make it `\s*` and it will work.. :)